# What is the difference between "shutdown /r" and "shutdown /g"?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, shutdown

I was reading some of the options for the `shutdown` command in windows, when I stumbled across the following option descriptions:

> ```
> /r         Full shutdown and restart the computer.
> /g         Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
>            rebooted, restart any registered applications.
> ```

I thought that when Windows restarts, every application would be closed on the shutdown procedure, and then started again on system boot.

Some possible considerations that come to mind for me are:

- Carryover from previous versions of Windows that performed some restart trickery
- Temporarily override the default behavior of system configuration

Is it any of these? None of these?

Comment: My guess would be to reload applications after startup that were running at the time of `shutdown /g`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### What is `shutdown /g`?

The `/g` option will restart applications that are registered for restart with the [RegisterApplicationRestart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373347(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

> The Windows Restart Manager (introduced in Windows Vista) supports
>   gracefully shutting down and restarting applications that registered
>   for restart with the [RegisterApplicationRestart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373347(v=vs.85).aspx) API.
>
> This functionality is used by Windows Update – thanks to the Restart
>   Manager, when I come yawning to my desktop PC in the morning, even
>   following a system restart, I have my Outlook, browser windows,
>   OneNote, Visual Studio, and Messenger all lined up as they were when I
>   went to bed.
>
> Suppose you want to initiate one of these “automagically restart
>   everything after restart” restarts. As of a few weeks ago, I had it in
>   my head that you have to write a small app that uses the Restart
>   Manager APIs (e.g. [RmStartSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373649(v=vs.85).aspx) and [RmShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373667(v=vs.85).aspx)) to do this.
>
> And then it hit me that the shutdown command must have support for
>   doing this. And indeed, it has:
>
> ```
> shutdown /g
> ```

Source [Restart Windows and Restart All Registered Applications: shutdown -g](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2011/08/14/restart-windows-and-restart-all-registered-applications-shutdown-g/)

Comment: @OlleKelderman Which is a pretty good indication of how useful this option is, generally speaking.

Comment: Funny, when my  computer restarts for an update, it most definitely does not have everything back where I left it. In fact, it generally has *nothing* back where I left it.

Comment: @KRyan It requires Windows Update to register the application with the Restart Manager. I guess that functionality is no longer used. Remember this was introduced in Vista. Windows Update has changed a lot since then.

Comment: @DavidPostill rather, it requires windows update to perform the restart in this manner, and the applications need to have registered themselves.

Comment: @Random832 Makes sense.