# Windows 10 Last Session Software Doesn't Start

Tags: windows-10

I am wondering why my system doesn't seem to save last shutdown session of my work. Isn't windows suppose to keep what softwares/folders open like before? I know how to fix the folder issue in file explorer option but not my softwares.

I know how to disable the feature or enable it at

Settings > Accounts > Sign-In Options

Scroll down to Privacy on the right and then set the following to on or off. But doesn't seem to work on my Windows 10 Pro 64bit 1803 with latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Not all applications can be restarted automatically.
The application itself must register for restart using the Windows API call
[RegisterApplicationRestart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerapplicationrestart).

If your software does not use this function, then it cannot be restarted
automatically.

To be sure, you might also try to use the command `shutdown /g`.

See the article
[What is the difference between “shutdown /r” and “shutdown /g”?](https://superuser.com/questions/1132091/what-is-the-difference-between-shutdown-r-and-shutdown-g)

Comment: Are you sure? I am talking about sage state when you shutdown? While using vanilla msi default Windows 10 home then upgraded to Pro I was able to have all softwares files text files open exact way before I shutdown. Right now I tried 2 clean install of Windows 10 Pro 1803 and 1809 I can't manage it. Please refer to these threads https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.winhelponline.com/blog/stop-auto-reopen-programs-restart-windows-10/amp/ and https://windowsreport.com/restore-apps-pc-reboot/ among some examples. I can't find a way to get this feature back.

Comment: Which applications are posting windows that you wish to keep? Text editors?

Comment: Yes ultraedit chrome and some apps. I am guessing I need to now use start or run once such a pity this was fixed for me.

Comment: Between Windows changes and application changes, options may be lost. Ultraedit may have [this](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultracompare/reload-previously-active-sessions.html), but I don't use this product.